Masoniteorm jointable(pivot)
I use masonite framework,But i can't enter value to pivot table?
class User(Model, SoftDeletesMixin, Authenticates):
    """User Model."""

    __fillable__ = ["name", "email", "password","username"]
    __hidden__ = ["password"]
    __auth__ = "email"

    @belongs_to_many("user_id","profile_id","id","id")
    def profiles(self):
        from app.models.Profile import Profile
        return Profile
class Profile(Model):
    """Profile Model"""


    @belongs_to_many("profile_id","user_id","id","id")
    def users(self):
        from app.models.User import User 
        return User

users tables - profiles table- Pivot table is (profile_user)
profile.users.push(active_user)
return empty list...
